# Migrate paragraph field

Tags: migrations, 9, paragraphs

I have events on my Drupal 7 websites and after the upgrade, I want to migrate those events to the Drupal 9 website. Event CT has a paragraph reference revision field to the 'event_date' paragraph on the Drupal 9 website. Inside the paragraph, there are fields like field_city, field_country, and others. On the Drupal 7 site, this paragraph has a location field referenced to the location entity. Now I want to migrate field_location (referenced to location, inside location there are the city, country fields) from Drupal 7 to feld_country, field_city on Drupal 9. I wrote migration_plus yml for event_paragraph migration, but I am unable to write migration for the reference field.

This is the migration file.

```yaml
id: paragraph_event_date
label: 'Paragraph event_date'
migration_group: event_migrate
migration_tags:
  - location
  - paragraph
source:
  plugin: d7_paragraphs_item
  bundle: event_date
  key: migrate
process:
  field_city:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_location
    process:
      value:
        plugin: format_date
  field_event_date_range:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_event_date
    process:
      value:
        plugin: format_date
        source: value
        from_format: 'U'
        to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
      end_value:
        plugin: format_date
        source: value2
        from_format: 'U'
        to_format: 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'
  field_sold_out:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_sold_out
    process:
      value: value
      langcode: language
  field_end_date_unset:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_end_date_unset
    process:
      value: value
      langcode: language
destination:
  plugin: 'entity_reference_revisions:paragraph'
  default_bundle: event_date
migration_dependencies: { }
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - twn_event_migrate
```

So my mapping should look like this.

```
 field_city = field_location <-- location <-- city
```

> [image: Drupal 9 paragraph__field_city]

> [image: Drupal 7 paragraph__field_location]

> [image: Drupal 7 location field]

Comment: Does this help? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/304157/71454

Comment: I saw this but in my case a bit different structure. In the example, they created paragraphs and then loaded them. But in my case, I want to change the existing paragraphs in drupal 7 to another paragraph in drupal 9. So I don't need to save them before migration. Thank you for your responce. Now I am trying to implement a new processor to for this porpose. If success I will provide my  solution also.