# Correct way to migrate multiple paragraphs from custom source

Tags: migrations, paragraphs

Drupal 9.4.5.  Looking to migrate Drupal 7 books into Drupal 9 paragraphs. Will need to migrate multiple paragraphs into D9 multi paragraph reference fields.  Below is outline of desired paragraph structure.

[image: Multiple Nested Paragraphs]

I have written a custom sql source plugin which provides the source fields I need.

My migration plan follows this guidance: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/304059/50789

1. Migrate all the paragraphs (**agenda_section** paragraphs)
2. Migrate the paragraphs which have the paragraphs migrated in step 1 as children (**nested** paragraphs)
3. Migrate the parent **nodes**.

The 1st migration is pretty straight forward.  The 2nd and 3rd, however, are a bit complicated since I need to associate single nodes and nested paragraphs to multiple child paragraphs.

The **field_body** fields for both nodes and nested paragraphs are of type Entity reference revisions, which allow for multiple child paragraphs.  But, what is the correct way to migrate multiple paragraphs?

After much research, the only example I have found for migrating multiple paragraphs is this:  https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_revisions/issues/2825565#comment-14331103

With respect to the 2nd migration (nested paragraphs):

I am using *hook_migrate_prepare_row()* in my migration module to add the child paragraph ids to each nested paragraph row.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_migrate_prepare_row().
 */
function sbn_migrations_migrate_prepare_row(Row $row, MigrateSourceInterface $source, MigrationInterface $migration) {
  switch ($migration->id()) {
    case 'nested': // Get the child paragraphs of each nested paragraph
      $mlids = array();
      $mlid = $row->getSourceProperty('mlid'); // Get this id
      $mlids = sbn_migrations_get_child_mlids($mlid); // Get all the child ids associated with this paragraph as an array
      $row->setSourceProperty('mlids', $mlids); // Add source column to this row called 'mlids' containing the child ids 
      break;
  }
}
```

This will output an array of mlids like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3187
    [1] => 3191
)
```

This array becomes my source **mlids** field.

So, my source fields for this migration: `nid, bid, title, plid, mlid, mlids`

This is the YAML I have come up with:

```
id: nested
# This is the 2nd migration of the nested paragraphs
[...]
process:
  field_title: title
  field_body2: # This is the entity reference revision field for child paragraphs
    -
      plugin: multiple_values
      source: mlids # This is the source field which contains array of child paragraph ids
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: agenda_section # This is the 1st migration of all paragraphs
      no_stub: true
    -  
     plugin: sub_process
     process:  
       target_id: '0'  
       target_revision_id: '1'
destination:
  plugin: entity_reference_revisions:paragraph
  default_bundle: nested
```

My question is:  As far as the people who know way more about this know, will this work?

If not, what do I need to do?